# reverse column values

Tags: mysql, replace

Here's my table data:

```
id __ firstname __ lastname __ salary
_____________________________________
1  __ John      __ Brown    __ 2,1000
2  __ David     __ Green    __ 3,8000
3  __ Matt      __ Blue     __ 1,6000
```

You see, `salary` contains 2 values, which are separated by a comma.
I want to reverse `salary` value; so John salary should be `1000,2`, David, `8000,3` and Matt `6000,1`.

How to do it with a sql query?

Comment: Must this be done in the actual query? Are you using a scripting or programming language of any sort?

Comment: @Asad: I prefer to run a query in phpMyAdmin.. but if no one finds help me, I should write a PHP script.

Comment: @Vucko: Could you explain more?

Comment: `You see, salary contains 2 values` Yuck! This one of the worst cases of non-normalization I've yet seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(salary,',',-1), ',', SUBSTRING_INDEX(salary,',',1));
```

Here is a demonstration: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/4473

Here's the thing about this, the primary purpose of SQL is to store and retrieve data, not to transform or modify it. You should ideally use PHP to do this.

Comment: Yes, but I have many rows in the table, and I think running a mysql query is faster than going with a script (and loop along rows and update one by one)